# Understanding the logic of an if let statement - variable used before being initialized

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, nsuserdefaults

So I'm following a tutorial on udemy and have this piece of code.

```
   let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")
    var items:[String]

    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String]
    {
        //
        items = tempItems
        items.append(textfield.text!)
    }
```

I understand the itemsObject and items array but I'm wondering why I'm not able to bypass the tempItems constant altogether like...

```
var items:[String]
if items = itemsObject as? [String]
{
items.append(textfield.text!)
}
```

I don't understand the purpose of the let tempItems constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")
```

itemsObject is now of type `Any?` So we need to do 2 things: cast it and check if it's nil

```
if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String]
```

is a shortcut for:

```
let tempItems1 = itemsObject as? [String] // cast to [String]?
if tempItems1 != nil {
    let tempItems2 = tempItems1! // we know its not nil, so force unwrap it to [String]
    ...
}
```

Hint:

`[String]?` is a string array that can be nil

`[String]` is a string array that can't be nil

Answer (score 0):

#### Optional binding is value-binding pattern matching, which is not equivalent to assignment

Consider the following simplified example:

```
let foo: Any = 1

if let bar = foo as? Int { /* ... */ }
```

So what are we doing in the last row here? We attempt to conditionally convert an `Any` instance (`foo`) to the type `Int`. The result of such an conditional type conversion (`as?`) is an `Optional`:

```
foo as? Int // type: Optional<Int>
```

Moving on, we try to *optionally bind* the possibly successful conversion to an immutable concrete instance of type `Int` (the `bar` property). See [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) in the language guide for details.

Now, the way we perform optional binding is simply syntactic sugar for [*value-binding pattern matching*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html), in the context of (given successful pattern match) attempting to bind an associated value of an `enum` case to a property. The syntactic sugar of optional binding is available to the extremly common `Optional<Wrapped>` enum type, whereas for other `enum` type, we need to use the common value-binding pattern syntax

```
if case let .anEnumCase(bindAssociatedValueToMe) = someEnumInstance { /* ... */ }

// alternatively
if case .anEnumCase(let bindAssociatedValueToMe) = someEnumInstance { /* ... */ }
```

I.e., the following two (three) are equivalent

```
// make use of syntactic sugar available for `Optional` enum
if let bar = foo as? Int { /* .. */ }

// or use the explicit value-binding pattern available to any
// enum with a case that holds and associated value
if case .some(let bar) = foo as? Int { /* .. */ }

// (for the latter: alternatively)
if case let .some(bar) = foo as? Int { /* .. */ }
```

And, to add some extra confusion to the matter, we also have another special syntactic sugar available to the special enum `Optional<Wrapped>` (the `.some(let bindWrappedToThis)` case, specifically), such that also the following is equivalent to the two above:

```
// using the sugar '_?' instead of '.some(_)', here replacing
// '... let .some(bar)' with '... let bar?'
if case let bar? = foo as? Int { /* .. */ }
```

---

The key to understanding the above is to understand the following:

1. An attempted type conversion, using `as?`, will result in an `Optional<Wrapped>` instance with  the `Wrapped` type being the target type of the type conversion. I.e., `someInstance as? SomeType` will result in an instance of `Optional<SomeType>`, that may be `nil` (`.none`), or may be wrapping a concrete instance of `SomeType` (`.some(someInstanceOfSomeType)`).
2. The type `Optional<Wrapped>` in Swift is, when leaving out all the special neatness/sugar, an enumeration,
3. Finally, that value-binding pattern matching is not the same as assignment.

1) is self-explanatory by its thorough description. To understand 2) & 3), we may study the following simple example, showing a custom "optional"-like `enum` with a `case` that holds a generic associated value, which, for a given instance of the `enum`, we try to conditionally bind to a property:

```
enum MyOptional<Wrapped> {
    case none
    case some(Wrapped)
}

// instantiate with a case with an associated value
let foo = MyOptional.some(1) // MyOptional<Int>.some(1)

// use value-binding pattern matching to conditionally
// access the associated value of the 'some(...)' case,
// given that 'foo' is '.some' (and not '.none')
if case .some(let bar) = foo { /* .. */ }
```

Notice the value-binding in the last line above, and compare to the non-sugared optional binding in the previous code snippet above.

---

Finally, note that you have means other than optional binding to access and perform operations on the (possible existing) wrapped value of an optional. E.g. using the [`map(_:)` method of `Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional/1539476-map), at the cost of clarity, we could condense your example (as well as make `items` immutable) in your top code snippet to the following:

```
let items = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items") as? [String])
    .map { $0 + [textfield.text!] } ?? []
```

Which, in a single expressions, make use of the following:

- conditional type conversion of the `UserDefaults` value to type `[String]`
- in case of successful type conversion, append `textField.text!` to the concrete `[String]` value and assign to `items`
- in case of unsuccessful type conversion, use the `nil` coalescing operator `??` to supply and empty array, `[]`, as a default value to `items`.